# Chai assertion for checking certain fields in an object array

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have an object array like below, and would like to assert against only certain fields in the array.

Object array -

```
var a = [{"key":"key2","value":"value2","updatedBy":"name1","Dttm":1516849776062},{"key":"key1","value":"value1","updatedBy":"name2","Dttm":1516849776060}]]
```

I just need to assert against key and value fields and not worry about updatedBy and Dttm, so something like,

```
expect(a)........([{"key":"key1","value":"value1"},{"key":"key2","value":"value2"}])
```

Comment: Not sure for this use case, chai things would be a good candidate - http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of 2 `chai` plugins: `chai-things` and `chai-like`.

[Chai Things](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things/):

> Chai Things adds support to Chai for assertions on array elements.

[Chai Like](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-like/):

> A JSON matcher for chai. This is really useful when you are testing API and want to ignore some attributes like: updatedAt, createdAt, id.

With both you can write a test like this for example:

```
//...
expect(a).to.contain.something.like({"key":"key1", "value":"value1"})
expect(a).to.contain.something.like({"key":"key2", "value":"value2"})
```

Here's how to install both:

```
npm install --save-dev chai-things chai-like
```

after installation tell `chai` to use the new plugins:

```
const chai = require('chai')

chai.use(require('chai-like'))
chai.use(require('chai-things'))
```

Links for further reading and examples:

chai-things: http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things/

chai-like: http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-like/

Comment: i keep getting assertion errors while using the above, i require chai in the test spec and then use chai.expect for all of the other assertions, with this setup i'm not sure how exactly i can use the above 2 to assert an object array w/o impacting other assertions

Comment: what errors do you get? did you add the chai plugins properly?
This should have no affect on other assertions.. or maybe I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: so, here is how i installed the plugins and used, i did npm install --save-dev so it gets added to my dev dependency and then in the spec file i have something like, const chai     = require('chai'); chai.use(require('chai-things'));chai.use(require('chai-like')); if i have the chai.use at the top of my spec file then i get this error "Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (type, code, ...) } to have property 'length'",  "at Proxy.allMethod (node_modules/chai-things/lib/chai-things.js:171:37)"

Comment: it errors at an assertion which looks like this, "expect(res.body.msg).to.be.an('array').to.have.lengthOf(1);"

Comment: Mm.. not sure if this is related to the original question. But try this instead:
`expect(res.body.msg).to.be.an('array').and.have.lengthOf(1)` (And make sure res.body.msg is indeed an array)

Comment: Ok, so in the test spec if i only have the assertions "expect(a).to.contain.something.like({"key":"key1", "value":"value1"})" and "expect(a).to.contain.something.like({"key":"key2", "value":"value2"})", it works fine, but if i have other assertions like the one that i described earlier it throws that weird assertion error... WRT chai, as i mentioned above i just have them and also i have const expect   = chai.expect; not sure if the assertion has to do something with it... Any idea?

Comment: Also the res.body.msg is indeed an array :), and weird thing is even having this assertion fails with the same exception, expect(res.body.msg[0]).to.be.an('object').that.has.all.keys('type', 'code', 'message', 'detail', 'source');, this was working fine before adding chai like and chai things

Comment: Just to clarify, is it **because** of the new plugins? also, can you copy here the assertion that throws the error?

Comment: Yep the error occurs only after adding the new plugins, below are some of the assertions that is failing

Comment: expect(res.body.msg).to.be.an('array').and.have.lengthOf(1); expect(res.body.msg[0]).to.be.an('object').that.has.all.keys('type', 'code', 'message', 'detail', 'source');

Comment: I see that `chai-things` indeed has an open bug for what you're describing. Sorry :\
https://github.com/chaijs/chai-things/issues/24

Comment: Ah, i see, no worries, let me take a look at that, if there is some workaround that i can use so both of these would work then that would be great!

Comment: So a workaround to overcome the assert exception would be, if we replace .all.keys with .should.include.keys, so this assertion "expect(res.body.msg[0]).to.be.an('object').that.has.all.keys‌​('type', 'code', 'message', 'detail', 'source');" would look like "expect(res.body.msg[0]).to.be.an('object')" and res.body.msg[0].should.include.keys('type', 'code', 'message', 'detail', 'source')

Comment: but i'm not sure how to have a "should.include" which would check all keys in an object..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163902/discussion-between-talzaj-and-sai).

Comment: Proxy is not allowing to me to access the chat, i've not brought my personnel laptop to work today :(,